# Custom meter in android

Tags: android

[image: **enter image description here**]

Need to create a meter of this sort..how to create buttons of different shape and arrange like the meter shown below.
or
just how to create buttons in different shapes
Thanks in advance

Comment: search for circular layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want advanced behaviour for these buttons you need to create a `custom button` by extending and overriding the existing `Button` provided by the SDK.
Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) for some theory.
However, if you just need to replace the images and use them as normal buttons you could just use an `ImageButton` with your custom image!

From a quick read, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507351/how-to-create-custom-button-in-android-using-xml-styles) could be a valid example for this.

As for the layout part, I would do something like this:

```
<Whatever root ViewGroup you are using for your activity>
    <ConstraintLayout to place correctly your buttons>
        <ImageButton1 blah blah />
                .........
        <ImageButtonN blah blah />
    </ConstraintLayout to place correctly your buttons>
</Whatever root ViewGroup you are using for your activity>
```

**EDIT**: @crgarridos suggested you a `CircularLayout`. My answer was influenced by the fact that I did not know that (it's not in the standard library pardon me for this) and wanted to avoid making you create a custom layout. By the way, I've searched for it and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116498/circular-layout) that might help more than my answer!

Comment: if i were to use image buttons how should i place those butons in circle?

Comment: I would suggest a `ConstraintLayout` in order to keep the relative order between the buttons.

Comment: I've added a layout idea

Comment: Basing on @crgarridos's comment I've edited the answer adding an alternative